# Is this piece of r code joining two tables and creating a plot?

Tags: r

could anyone please explain to me the function of this code? and what it is intenteded to do?

```
airports %>%
  semi_join(flights, c("faa" = "dest")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(lon, lat))+
  geom_point()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get confused by a piece of code, break it down in smaller steps and see what each line does. If you are not aware of certain functions, it's documentation is available at `?function_name` (example - `?semi_join`).

It seems that the datasets `airports` and `flights` are from package `nycflights13`. Load the libraries that are required for running the code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)
library(ggplot2)
```

`semi_join` keeps the common rows that match between the two datasets. The column to match on which the datasets are joined is `faa` in `airports` and `dest` in `flights`. If you don't know how join works take a smaller example and try this code on it. You may also take a look at [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right) for a general explanation of different join functions.

```
airports %>% semi_join(flights, c("faa" = "dest"))

#   faa   name                               lat    lon   alt    tz dst   tzone            
#   <chr> <chr>                             <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>            
# 1 ABQ   Albuquerque International Sunport  35.0 -107.   5355    -7 A     America/Denver   
# 2 ACK   Nantucket Mem                      41.3  -70.1    48    -5 A     America/New_York 
# 3 ALB   Albany Intl                        42.7  -73.8   285    -5 A     America/New_York 
# 4 ANC   Ted Stevens Anchorage Intl         61.2 -150.    152    -9 A     America/Anchorage
# 5 ATL   Hartsfield Jackson Atlanta Intl    33.6  -84.4  1026    -5 A     America/New_York 
# 6 AUS   Austin Bergstrom Intl              30.2  -97.7   542    -6 A     America/Chicago  
# 7 AVL   Asheville Regional Airport         35.4  -82.5  2165    -5 A     America/New_York 
# 8 BDL   Bradley Intl                       41.9  -72.7   173    -5 A     America/New_York 
# 9 BGR   Bangor Intl                        44.8  -68.8   192    -5 A     America/New_York 
#10 BHM   Birmingham Intl                    33.6  -86.8   644    -6 A     America/Chicago  
# … with 91 more rows
```

After running the code, the above dataframe is plotted with `ggplot2` library where x-axis is `lon` and y-axis is `lat`. It uses `geom_point` to plot as scatterplot.

```
airports %>%
  semi_join(flights, c("faa" = "dest")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(lon, lat))+
  geom_point()
```

[image]